# Размер экземпляра класса с нестатической функцией

Tags: java, java-me

При создании 10 экземпляров одного класса в JavaME, у которого есть нестатическая функция, будет затрачено оперативной памяти в десять раз больше, чем при создании одного экземпляра этого класса? Или это зависит от реализации виртуальной машины?

Answer (score 3):

Размер экземпляра класса зависит от реализации класса Object. Если есть хоть какие-то данные в нём, то да, будет в десять раз больше. Однако, нестатическая функция тут вообще ни при чём. Её наличие или отсутствие никак не влияет на размер экземпляра класса. Виртуальной машине не надо хранить указатели на эти функции в экземпляре классов, так как у Java строгая статическая типизация. Нельзя просто добавить или удалить метод у конкретного экземпляра. Состав методов хранится к классе (экземпляре класса Class).

Comment: Почему в большинстве литературы рекомендуют использовать статичные методы, если эффект тот же?

Comment: Так правильно рекомендуют. Если метод действительно может быть статическим, то незачем передвать this-указатель. Если же метод должен использовать что-то из данных или методов класса, то передавать ссылку всё равно придётся. Тогда использовать статический метод даже хуже, чем обычный: вам придётся явно передавать ссылку на экземпляр класса и это может оказаться даже менее эффективным, чем встроенная передача this. Так что эффект совсем не тот же. Статические методы они на то и статические.

Comment: Ну раз на скорости выполнения и объемах потраченной памяти не сказывается, значит сделано просто для удопочитаемости кода.
Скажем как Math.Abs() статично нет необходимости в экземплярах или block.Draw() тут интуитивно понятно, что "блок" какой-то нарисует себя.

Comment: Это сделано в интересах реализации идеологии ООП. Такова его природа. Разница между статическими методами и нестатическими в двух моментах: 
1) статический метод не требует экземпляров каких-либо классов (кроме экземпляра класса Class), так что и this передавать в него не нужно;
2) статический метод не может быть переопределён (что более чем естественно).